# onTouched never called when using custom component with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to get nested / sub-forms working with custom components that use the ControlValueAccessor interface.

I have a stackblitz demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jg2p8c

I cant work out why changing the Info form (the yellow box) doesnt alter the `touched` property on the `infoForm` object.

Comment: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form will simplify your life :). A lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` is not enough. You also need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` [interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor), meaning you take the `registerOnTouched(fn)` argument function, and then you call it when your control get's touched. Otherwise the forms are not connected.

```
onTouched = () => void;

constructor() {
  this.form.statusChanges.pipe(
    first(() => this.form.touched),
  ).subscribe(
    () => this.onTouched()
  )
}

registerOnTouched(fn) {
  this.onTouched = fn;
}
```

Comment: In my example, the `Info-panel` Component extends `SubForm` which implements `ControlValueAccessor`

Comment: Nice, so just cal the onTouched when the inner form gets touched.